# How can I remove my ownership of a question that I have asked?

Tags: support, moderation

When we try to question delete the questions that we have asked and received some answers, it says we can't delete it. But if we need to hide the ownership of that     question How can we do it?

Actually when we asked questions those will become public for search engines even. 
And our ownership of those questions will be shown to everyone.
How can I remove my ownership of a question that I have asked?

Answer (score 5):

Send a request through the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the site and let them know you wish to disassociate your account from a post. Include a link to the post and the author will be listed as anonymous.